# How do I bind to a system framework with Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac, cryptotokenkit

I'm in the proces of making an app for interacting with smartcards.
For that I'd like to use the CryptoTokenKit Framework which is standard on a Mac (located at /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework).

This link says that it's possible to bind frameworks in a Mac project:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/native-references/

I've created an ApiDefinition.cs file and a StrucsAndEnums.cs file using the following sharpie command:
sharpie bind -framework ./CryptoTokenKit.framework -sdk macosx10.13 -o ~/CryptoTokenKitBinding

I can't find any info on the internet how to implement the above mentioned files and start using the framework.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `Xamarin.Mac` binding project within a solution.

Add a `NativeReference` to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework
```

Bind it using `sharpie`:

```
sharpie bind \
    -o CryptoTokenKitFramework \
    -namespace CryptoTokenKit \
    -sdk macosx10.13 \
    -f /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework
```

There is a mismatch between the binding project template and the output of sharpie, so you can either delete ApiDefinition.cs and add ApiDefinitions.cs or just overwrite the template created one:

```
mv CryptoTokenKitFramework/ApiDefinitions.cs CryptoTokenKitFramework/ApiDefinition.cs
```

There will be a number of attributes like (versions will change across them):

```
[Watch (4,0), TV (11,0), Mac (10,12), iOS (10,0)]
```

As these are ***private*** frameworks on iOS, Watch, TV, so strip those platforms out. Leave the `Mac` attribute and the original version:

```
[Mac (10,11)]
```

Note: `PlatformAttribute` is obsolete but `sharpie` is still using it (assuming backwards version compatibility(?)), so you can use `Introduced` if you really want to clean up the build output:

```
[Introduced (PlatformName.MacOSX, 10, 11, PlatformArchitecture.Arch64)]
```

There will be a few `[Verify]` attributes that have to be reviewed/corrected. i.e. `TKSmartCardUserInteraction.Cancel` and  `TKSmartCardSlot.MakeSmartCard` should both be methods not properties.

Example / Generated:

```
// -(TKSmartCard * _Nullable)makeSmartCard;
[NullAllowed, Export ("makeSmartCard")]
[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
TKSmartCard MakeSmartCard { get; }
```

Corrected:

```
// -(TKSmartCard * _Nullable)makeSmartCard;
[NullAllowed, Export("makeSmartCard")]
TKSmartCard MakeSmartCard();
```

Fix the rest of the `[Verify]` attributes and compiler errors, there are a bunch of bad method signatures, pointers, return types, etc.. that are generated and need corrected.

Note: TO make your life easier, make sure that you are using the latest `Sharpie` version:

```
Version:  3.4.0
SHA1:     c12859dac8d43121b5a9ed866a0db8409f9df817
URL:      https://dl.xamarin.com/objective-sharpie/ObjectiveSharpie-3.4.0.pkg
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question @SushiHangover. Is there a reason why you use the framework in Xcode with Sharpie but add the system framework as a reference?

Comment: I get the error, when I want to compile: /Users/Koen/Developer/poc_digid/CryptoTokenKitFramework/CryptoTokenKitFramework/BTOUCH: Error BI1017: bgen: Do not know how to make a signature for Security.SecCertificate in parameter `certificateRef' from CryptoTokenKitFramework.TKTokenKeychainCertificate.Constructor (BI1017) (CryptoTokenKitFramework)

Comment: In the following piece of code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0d1aad180c111b726be1ec14dddd564e

Comment: @KoenHendriks The framework provided by the OS is what everyone has installed, but the Xcode version has the headers needed by sharpie.